# Correct reference to VS120COMNTOOLS is lost when refreshing EntityFramework 6 .1 model from database

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have tried previous solution of manually setting the variable VS120COMNTOOLS to correct location using Visual Studio 2013 command prompt. I then started the VS using 'devenv' command.

When Visual Studio opens and try to build my project, I don't get the original error stating the required EntityFramework DLL is not found. Instead I get errors in DBModel.cs and Model.context.cs. In each file there is one line 'ErrorGeneratingOutput'

I am locked in a loop as follows.

1. I update model from database (refresh or adding a new table)
2. The build does not work giving the following error.

The host threw an exception while trying to resolve the assembly reference

```
'%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\EntityFramework.dll'. The transformation will not be run. The following Exception was thrown:
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(String path)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.ResolveAssemblyReference(String assemblyReference)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ResolveAssemblyReferences(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, TemplateProcessingSession session) C:\tmp\PatternSpyGUI\PatternSpyGUI\Model.tt 0   0   PatternSpyGUI
```

1. I quit VS and using the command prompt set VS120COMNTOOLS correctly and start VS.
2. Now when I try to build, I get the above stated errors in DBModel.cs and Model.context.cs.

How can I get out of this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As per instructions online, I ran the command to change the location of VS120COMNTOOLS and received the same error. Turns out I was encasing the path in quotes. Running the same command without quotes as below fixed the issue for me.

set VS120COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7

My edmx files seem to be working after that.